# DataBindingUtil not found in my mainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I'm adding in my gradle

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityMain3Binding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMain3Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        binding=DataBindingUtil // don't found 

        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        binding.EdName.setText("test text");
    }
```

I need help or good and new tutorial to understand dataBinding

Answer (score 19):

You also need to enable data binding in your app-level `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1-In your app’s build.gradle set data binding as usual

2-Add the compiler dependency

3- Then apply the plugin at the top of the file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    buildFeatures {
     dataBinding true
   }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to enable data binding in build.gradle

buildFeatures {
dataBinding true
viewBinding true
}